# Finding the minimum values from different columns according to the criteria and multiplying by another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, min, sumproduct

I normally search and find the answers to my questions on this site, but I could not solve this problem. I ask for your help.

I have a table and there are different prices in different columns in this table. I need to find the lowest values from these columns and multiply by the quantity numbers without creating a new column. While finding these minimum values, I need to find them according to a criteria. Since this table will stretch downwards, I must use horizontal formulas.

[image: Table 1 Image]

| Quantity | Criteria | Column 1 | Price | Column 2 | Price | Column 3 | Price | Column 4 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YES | Material 1 | $100,00 | Material 1 | $90,00 | Material 1 | $75,00 | Material 1 | $100,00 |
| 2 | YES | Material 2 | $120,00 | Material 2 | $150,00 | Material 2 | $220,00 | Material 2 | $210,00 |
| 1 | YES | Material 3 | $140,00 | Material 3 | $140,00 | Material 3 | $145,00 | Material 3 | $130,00 |
| 4 | NO | Material 4 | $150,00 | Material 4 | $90,00 | Material 4 | $80,00 | Material 4 | $80,00 |
| 2 | NO | Material 5 | $90,00 | Material 5 | $60,00 | Material 5 | $55,00 | Material 5 | $56,00 |
| 1 | NO | Material 6 | $15,00 | Material 6 | $15,00 | Material 6 | $20,00 | Material 6 | $10,00 |
| 3 | YES | Material 7 | $150,00 | Material 7 | $200,00 | Material 7 | $180,00 | Material 7 | $90,00 |

The results should be: `(1*75) + (2*120) + (1*130) + 0 + 0 + 0 + (3*90)`

I've tried `=SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(A3,SEQUENCE(ROWS` formulas but no luck. excel doesn't support sequence. I can't write an "if" formula next to each column because I shouldn't increase the columns of the table.

Comment: Office 365 Excel does support Sequence.  I assume you do not have Office 365?

Comment: Also can you put the data in a markdown text table so we can copy paste?  It will help us help you.

Comment: Hello Scott. I'm using Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2019. I added the link to the file. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1taXLRthUGoBI2CUXS7K0J1hG068RAH6VbmmWfkIVPls/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: *"without creating a new column"* - how strictly? Maybe an invisible column is ok, or one on another sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Office 2019 which does not have the dynamic array formula we need to use SUBTOTAL and OFFSET to return an array of the MINIMUMS of each row to SUMPRODUCT.  Then add the other criteria to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B8="YES")*A2:A8,SUBTOTAL(5,OFFSET(C1:J1,ROW(C2:J8)-MIN(ROW(C2:J8))+1,0)))
```

[image]

One note, for me the numbers transferred as text not numbers.  Make sure they are true numbers or this will not work.

For those with the Dynamic Array formula we can ditch the Volatile Offset:

```
=SUM(BYROW(ROW(A2:A8),LAMBDA(z,INDEX(A:A,z)*(INDEX(B:B,z)="YES")*MIN(INDEX(C:J,z,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(C:J),1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Another question. If there are numbers in material name columns, formula takes them to calculation. Is there a way to only consider price columns in the whole table?

Comment: That is a new question.  Please ask it in a new post.